# Access child's variable in parent passed through function parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I am trying to access some specific variable that are only available in a child class. But the problem is that I recieve the parent of this class by parameter. Even with casting I can't seem to be able to access the members. **Can it be done?**

```
public class ENUMTranslator : ITranslate<RedisData>
{
    public string Translate(RedisData message)
    {
        string bitMask = message.AssociatedParam.ParamDictionary["Bitmask"];

        var enumerations = (EnumParams)message.AssociatedParam.EnumDictionary
    }
}
```

The thing is that the data is not in message itself but inside `AssociatedParam` Which is the parent class of `EnumParams`.

The `EnumDictionary` is what I am trying to access that should be in `EnumParams`, but I just can't access it.

EDIT : Here is the EnumParam class.

```
message.AssociatedParams
```

is a GAPParam

```
public class EnumParams : GAPParam
{
    #region Class Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary for the enums linking name with hex value
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<string, string> _enumDictionary;

    #endregion // Class Members

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary for the enums linking name with hex value
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, string> EnumDictionary
    {
        get { return _enumDictionary; }
        set { _enumDictionary = value; }
    }

    #endregion // Properties

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise the dictionaries
    /// </summary>
    public EnumParams()
    {
        _enumDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    #endregion // Constructor
}
```

I cannot see it with intellisense and it would not compile either.

Comment: Which members are inaccessible? It isn't understood from your question.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot access it?  Is a compilation error thrown?  Does Intellisense not recognize it?  In addition, what is the relationship between RedisData and EnumParams?

Comment: message.AssociatedParam.Something does not compile ..?
or is unable to cast to EnumParams ?

Comment: Probably parenthesis problem: instead of `(EnumParams)message.AssociatedParam.Something` should be `((EnumParams)message).AssociatedParam.Something`...

Comment: If I had to venture a loose guess based on the very unclear details provided so far, I'd suspect that you're not casting the right object.  I'm guessing what you really want is ((EnumParams)message.AssociatedParam).Something.

Comment: @pwas I think your params are still in the wrong place pwas.  Considering that message is RedisData that appears to have nested properties on it, the EnumParams instance to be casted is most likely AssociatedParam, not the RedisData itself.  All speculation of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you *could* cast `message.AssociatedParam` to an `EnumParams`:

```
var enumerations = ((EnumParams)message.AssociatedParam).EnumDictionary
```

but if `message.AssociatedParam` is not castable to an `EnumParams` then it will fail at runtime.  Some way to mitigate the risk:

- should `EnumDictionary` be on `GAPParam` instead?  Even if it's virtual or abstract?
- should `message.AssociatedParam` be an `EnumDictionary` instead of a `GAPParam`?
- do a check before casting to make sure `message.AssociatedParam` is an `EnumParams` - but then what do you do if its not?